# Set the background color of a ScrollPane in JavaFX 8

Tags: javafx, javafx-8

I cannot set the background color of a ScrollPane in the latest version of JavaFX 8 (java 8  b-110 and above versions).  So I need to know whether this is a permanent issue or temporarily (which can be Fixed in later versions)?

Comment: possible duplicate of [ScrollPanes in JavaFX 8 always have gray background](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22952531/scrollpanes-in-javafx-8-always-have-gray-background)

Answer (score 10):

I ended up using `-fx-background:green;` instead of `-fx-background-color:green;` because `-fx-background-color` only set the colour for the borders of `ScrollPane`.

Comment: it's worth to know that color with transparency like `rgba(255.0, 255.0, 255.0, 0.75)` does not work with this method

Answer (score 2):

It looks like some additional CSS is needed in order to be able to set ScrollPane backgrounds to whatever color you like.  See this question:

[ScrollPanes in JavaFX 8 always have gray background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22952531/scrollpanes-in-javafx-8-always-have-gray-background)

Comment: that too an option we can set styles instead of calling a class we can use the code like  scrollPane.setStyle("-fx-background-color:green;");

Answer (score 0):

May be This Can Help..

[JavaFX ScrollPane border and background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17540137/javafx-scrollpane-border-and-background)

..

[JavaFX Hide ScrollPane gray border](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12899788/javafx-hide-scrollpane-gray-border)

....

[JavaFX ScrollPane showing objects outside of viewport](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15765034/javafx-scrollpane-showing-objects-outside-of-viewport)

....

[JAVAFX 2.0 How can i dynamically change the content in a scrollPane?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13477653/javafx-2-0-how-can-i-dynamically-change-the-content-in-a-scrollpane)

Comment: I understand your comment but use that comment in the java version java 8 b 110 and more version as we know latest java version is java 8 b 120...  please kindly put this code in your system after installing the java version which i recommends to u.. i Hope u will understand my question buddy.....                                                                                                                                          ScrollPane sp = new ScrollPane();
    sp.setStyle("-fx-background-color:green;");